# How to copy multiple files to a new folder in a new path in one command?

Tags: command-line, files, directory, copy, cp

[These are the files I want to copy over][1]

Example command I have tried but does not work:

cp **permanent_waiver_*** /existingpath/**newfolder1**/**newfolder2**

This would give me error like no such file or directory.

Comment: You should give us the actual command that you are using and more importantly, the complete and unredacted error.  Please use monospace formatting by using backticks so that we can parse the information as it would appear in your terminal. Adding additional formatting and punctuation only adds ambiguity.  Also, can you tell us if the source and destination directories actually exist?  If you start a path with `/` it is an absolute path and I doubt that `/existingpath` exists on your system

Answer (score 0):

You have to create your new folder structure first, but this shouldn't be hard.

```
mkdir -p /existingpath/newfolder1/newfolder2

cp permanent_waiver_* /existingpath/newfolder1/newfolder2
```

So, it's really two commands.